# Aspect exception handler

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have an AOP checked exception handler. The idea is to get rid of all repetitive code using Aspects.

```java
@Aspect
public class DbAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(Transactional)")
    public void transactionalMethods() {/* Empty */}

    @Around("transactionalMethods()")
    public Object procede(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
        try(Connection connection = DBConnectionPool.INSTANCE.getConnection()) {
            JDBCUtils.setCurrentConnection(connection);
            return call.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("SQLException happend");
        } finally {
            JDBCUtils.removeCurrentConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

The code that may throw checked exception

```java
@Override
@Transactional(read = true)
public Optional<User> select(SqlSpecification specification) {
    return JDBCUtils.select(JDBCUtils.getConnection(),
            specification.getSql(SQL_SELECT_USER),
            userResultSetHandler,
            specification.getParameters());
}
```

The problem is that i get compile time error `Unhandled exception type SQLException`, even though i have the code that have to handle all exceptions.

I use Maven `pom.xml` to build the project.

```xml
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.0</junit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.source-target.version>11</java.source-target.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.4</aspectj.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <source>${java.source-target.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.source-target.version}</target>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <complianceLevel>${java.source-target.version}</complianceLevel>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <XnoInline>true</XnoInline>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have already seen some solutions but they didn't work for me.

Comment: The compiler has not idea of an aspect intercepting this method at compile time. You'll still have to declare checked exceptions on intercepted methods.

Comment: Exactly! Imagine a simpler situation: You call a method throwing a checked exception and have a try-catch block in the calling method. It is exactly the same: You have to declare the checked exception in the method where it occurs because the compiler cannot know which other methods might in the future call the method causing the exception and then either handle the exception or not. Imagine that the called method is in a library used by thousands of projects. The fact that you use AOP does not magically make that issue disappear. 

Comment: Some small details: If your `@Transactional` annotation does not happen to be declared in the exact same package as the aspect, you better use a fully qualified class name in your pointcut such as `@annotation(my.package.Transactional)`, otherwise it will not work. Please also note that in your POM you use two different AspectJ versions 1.9.4 vs. 1.9.6, which is also not a good idea. You want to align them.